# using the MASTER database in SQL Server for data tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, master-db

I've started doing some SQL consulting work for a former colleague.  He has SQL Server Express 2014 and it looks like the two previous consultants had no compunction about setting up his main work tables in MASTER, as opposed to anywhere else.

I looked in his DATA folder and looks like his MASTER database is 27 GB and the log file isn't much smaller.  I'm surprised that SQL Express hasn't complained about the database size, for starters.
I suspect the two previous consultants have more experience than me but to me this looks like a terrible setup and that you shouldn't have your main work tables (or any work tables) in MASTER.

Can I get some advice on this? Is this some trick for getting around the 10 GB Express Edition database size, or is it sloppy design just waiting to fail?  He's the only one using the server, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Probably to get round the 10GB limit. I wasn't aware of this loophole but seems some people are suggesting it on the internet https://akawn.com/blog/2017/05/how-to-bypass-the-sql-server-express-database-size-limit/

Comment: Why not just upgrade to SQL: Server, regular edition?  It's available at no cost.

Comment: My key question is, how risky is it to store data tables (large or not) in the MASTER database?

Comment: @SezMe: the **Developer** edition is available free of costs for development and testing purposes - but it isn't allowed to be used for **production** use - those licenses **aren't free!**